# JBoss AS 7 - NoSuchMethodError org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.init()V

Tags: jboss, axis, jboss7.x, nosuchmethoderror, wss4j

I am migrating from JBoss 5 -> JBoss 7 and according to https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7, local resources packaged in WEB-INF/lib of a war should loaded prior to inter deployment dependencies.

Within my WEB-INF/lib directory I have the wss4j (version 1.5.7) library jar which contains the Transform.init() method.

After I deploy my app and run it I get the following error.

> ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/].[Resteasy]]
>   (http--127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw
>   exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.init()V
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:340)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:214)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:190)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:540)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:502)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:119)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>   [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform.init()V
>           at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.(WSSConfig.java:81) [wss4j-1.5.2.jar:]
>           at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getNewInstance(WSSConfig.java:95)
>   [wss4j-1.5.2.jar:]
>           at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.(WSSConfig.java:47)
>   [wss4j-1.5.2.jar:]
>           at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.(WSSecurityEngine.java:51)
>   [wss4j-1.5.2.jar:]
>           at org.apache.ws.security.handler.WSHandler.(WSHandler.java:62)
>   [wss4j-1.5.2.jar:]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
>           at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:177) [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
>           at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:100)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getJavaClass(WSDDDeployableItem.java:353)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.makeNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:295)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDChain.makeNewInstance(WSDDChain.java:125)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getGlobalRequest(WSDDDeployment.java:473)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getGlobalRequest(FileProvider.java:269)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getGlobalRequest(AxisEngine.java:365)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:126)
>   [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784) [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767) [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443) [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366) [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812) [axis-1.4.jar:]
>           
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_05]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
>   [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.2.Final.jar:]
>           ... 19 more

Answer (score 1):

From the info I could find, it seems the method is not available in xmlsec after version 1.4. You could try using an older version of the jar such as:

http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/santuario/xmlsec/1.4.2/xmlsec-1.4.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem and I solved it setting up the following JBoss' deployment exclusion (in 7.1.1) in META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="deployment.javaee.api" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
    <module name="deployment.javaee.api">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javaee.api" export="true">
                <imports>
                    <exclude path="org/apache/xml/security/**" />
                </imports>
            </module>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

From https://community.jboss.org/message/747491#747491.